# Joomla Component Permissions

Tags: joomla

In Joomla 2.5 I have a **custom component** installed that is only available to the Administrator. I would like to make this component available to the Manager Group as well.

Can someone please tell me what file I must edit? Is it an [XML file](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_ACL) in the administrator/components/name_here/? Or is this a lot more complicated than I think?

I hope I am reading the right file, this Joomla system is a mad hatter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not just an XML file your component will need to check the permissions a user has.

Since Joomla! 1.6 there is an extensive Access Control (ACL) mechanism implemented for front-end and backend access. You can define an unlimited number of Groups all with different access levels on a per component basis (this presumes that the component is written correctly).  The default groups that are created with the initial setup can be deleted or renamed and **may not to exist on all installations**, users can create groups of any name with any range of permissions.

I would recommend starting with the [Access Control List/2.5/Tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/ACL_Tutorial_for_Joomla_1.6) this will give you a better understanding of the new ACL.

Then from the "[Developing a Model-View-Controller Component/2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5)" tutorial, re-read "[Adding ACL](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_ACL)" article, if you need custom rules you will probably want to read the [Adding ACL Rules to your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_ACL_rules_to_your_component) article as well.